# UIUserNotificationTypeAlert // UIUserNotificationSettings // registerUserNotificationSettings are deprecated while building WebDriverAgentRunner

Tags: xcode

I get these errors (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert // UIUserNotificationSettings // registerUserNotificationSettings are deprecated) when I build WebDriverAgentRunner.
I tried many way to resolve it even removed the Xcode and installed it again but cannot figure it out. I put a screenshot too.
thank you.
[image: here is a screenshot]

almost everything I found on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i continue with appium 2.0 on bash window